# kubectl set image throws error: the server doesn't have a resource type deployment"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Environment: Win 10 home, gcloud sdk v240.0 kubectl added as a gcloud sdk component, Jenkins 2.169
I am running a Jenkins pipeline in which I call a windows batch file as a post-build action.
In that batch file, I am running:

```
kubectl set image deployment/py-gmicro py-gmicro=%IMAGE_NAME%
```

I get this

```
error: the server doesn't have a resource type deployment
```

However, if I run the batch file directly from the command prompt, it works fine. Looks like it has an issue only if I run it from Jenkins.

Looked at a similar thread on stackoverflow, however that user was using bitbucket (instead of Jenkins).

Also, there was no certified answer on that thread. I cannot continue on that thread since I am not allowed to comment (50 reputation required)

Comment: Can you add configuration file of deployment?

Comment: Seems silly, but can you try adding the s? 'deployments'

Comment: Grigor - thanks for taking the time to respond- I am new to this - would you consider giving me steps on how to get the config file?

Comment: I would do `get-credentials` first, then `set image`, as post-build action.

Answer (score 0):

Just was answered on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55625764/10891037)

> I've had this error fixed by explicitly setting the namespace as an argument, e.g.:

```
kubectl set image -n foonamespace deployment/ms-userservice.....
```

Refrence:
https://www.mankier.com/1/kubectl-set-image#--namespace

Comment: This did not work for me. Can you please detailed steps that you used? Perhaps I missed something.