# the server doesn't have a resource type "deployment" in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In my jenkins pipeline, I've configured like that one.

```
    stage('Deploying into k8s'){
        steps{
            sh 'kubectl set image deployment/my-api my-api=ppshein/myapi:${BUILD_NUMBER} -n my-ns --record'
        }
    }
```

and when I've run Jenkins pipeline, I've encountered following error message:

```
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "deployment"
```

> But when I ssh to my EC2 instance and run same command, it was working successfully.

Please let me know I missed something to configure in Jenkins or somehow user authentication in my server?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874577/kubernetes-set-image-missing-resource-type-deployment

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu it was not correct that I found yesterday as well.

Comment: @PPShein could you clarify for me your last comment? Have this link showed you that your configuration was incorrect or solutions posted in this link were incorrect.

Comment: @DawidKruk Problem is when I ssh to my jenkins instance and type `kubectl set image deployment/my-api my-api=ppshein/myapi:${BUILD_NUMBER} -n my-ns --record`, it was working. But in Jenkins pipeline, that command is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to run other command like `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx` instead of the one you provided? Have you run into any issues using it?

Answer (score 0):

User Jenkins' home directory must have `.kube/config`,for example
`/var/lib/jenkins/.kube/config`