# Forbidden error while describe/scale deployment by user system:node:ip.xx

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding

I'm trying to execute K8S kubectl cmds from inside the container(name: autodeploy).
I have configured ClusterRole, ServiceAccount and ClusterRoleBinding. But getting Forbidden error while performing Describe and Scale actions on K8S Deployments.

> **Error from server (Forbidden):** deployments.apps "test-deployment" is
> forbidden: User "system:node:ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal" cannot get
> resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "abc"

autodeploy container also in same namespace abc

**ClusterRole:**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: autodeploy
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["deployments", "deployments/scale", "pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "update"]
```

**ServiceAccount:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: autodeploy
  namespace: abc
```

**ClusterRoleBinding:**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: autodeploy
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: autodeploy
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: autodeploy
    namespace: abc
```

Comment: what does `kubectl auth can-i get deployment  -n abc --as system:serviceaccount:abc:autodeploy` return ?

Comment: @P.... this returns
`Warning: the server doesn't have a resource type 'deployment'
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874577/kubernetes-set-image-missing-resource-type-deployment

Comment: Managed to solve it ?